# How Can I Grep For Two Different Strings and Print Them?

Tags: bash, grep

My data looks like this below:

```
STX=ANAA:1+5013546100917:KELLOGG COMPANY (GB) LIMITED+5000119000006:TESCO STORES PLC+160811:134338+63010+PIONEER+INVFIL+B'
MHD=1+INVFIL:9'
TYP=0700+INVOICES'
SDT=5013546100917:12191+KELLOGG COMPANY (GB) LIMITED+THE KELLOGG BUILDING:TALBOT ROAD:MANCHESTER::M16 OPU+151194288'
CDT=5000119000006:5000119000006+TESCO STORES PLC+BOUGHT LEDGER DEPARTMRENT:TESCO HOUSE:PO BOX 506:CARDIFF:CF4 4TS+220430231'
FIL=9476+1+160811'
FDT=160313+160315'
MTR=7'
MHD=2+INVOIC:9'
CLO=5000119008510:0100851:4420009+TESCO (CO ANTRIM)+KILBEGS ROAD:BALLYMENA ROAD:ANTRIM:AT:BT41 4NN'
IRF=92349489+160314+160314'
```

And I want to GREP for "FIL=" and "IRF=" and print them out to see the results.

I have tried various options none of them work!

```
zgrep -i 'FIL=\|IRF=\|' `zgrep -il "5000119000006" *201609*`

zgrep "FIL=|IRF=" `zgrep -il "50001190000006" *201609*'
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: I want the screen to show/print the following

Comment: FIL=9476+1+160811' and IRF=92349489+160314+160314'

Comment: There's hundreds of files to search through

Comment: Use this: `grep 'FIL=\|IRF='`

Answer (score 0):

if file are zipped:

```
zegrep 'FIL=|IRF=' *gz
```

if files are regular files (not zipped):

```
egrep 'FIL=|IRF=' *
```

*so you should try like this:*

- first filter data with `50001190000006`
- if data present in file then search for `FIL=|IRF=` from the file

  ```
  zgrep -q '5000119000006' test.file;if [ $? -eq 0 ];then egrep 'FIL=|IRF=' test.file; fi
  FIL=9476+1+160811'
  IRF=92349489+160314+160314'
  ```

Replace `test.file` with `201611`(actual file name in your system)

Comment: /gis/data/archive/as2/KEU_ORBIT/o> zgrep '50001190000006' *2016100*.gz |egrep 'FIL=|IRF=' *
ksh: /usr/bin/egrep: arg list too long

Comment: for some reason this did not work.  I can, obviously, grep using zgrep "50001190000006" *201611* but the command you gave doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like your files are not named with .gz extension- try with out .gz - see update

Comment: @StuartFung - see updated answer - sorry it took longer to respond.